# Plotting three columns in Python

Tags: python, plot

Hello I am a newbie in python. I have a dataframe that contains 3 columns:
FG%, FT%, 3pts%.
i want to display different rows on the same plot for each column as the below picture.
however, for each column the labels will be different.
For example the FG% above 50% is great and FT% above 90% is exceptional (Also explained in the picture below)
Can you help me achieve this plot please? [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ha6SX.jpg)

i couldn't create it using python

Comment: what have you tried so far ?
the question needs sufficient code for a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: the question needs code or an attempt.